# Parallel IO Causes Random Text Output in Terminal

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm using

```
import Control.Concurrent.ParallelIO.Global

main = parallel_ (map processI [1..(sdNumber runParameters)])  >> stopGlobalPool
```

where

```
processI :: Int -> IO ()
```

is some function, which reads data from file, processes it and writes it to another file. **No output to terminal.** The problem is when I run the program with `+RTS -N8` the terminal is flooded with random text like

```
piptufuht teata thtsieieo ocnsno e nscsdeoe qnqvuduee   ernvnstetiirioasanlil lolwynya. .s
w
a s s uY Ysosopuuue's'nvpvdeeee n dpdp rerdodoub beada
bub lel y
```

What is happening? Without +RTS there is no clutter. I couldn't reproduce the behavior with a more simple (suitable to post here) program.

GHC 7.0.3 if that matters

Comment: You didn't say whether or not you are outputting text to the terminal.  The text from your various threads can get interwoven, you must serialize your terminal IO, usually by selecting a single thread to do the printing.  I think there's a package for exactly this purpose, but it isn't hard either way.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: IIRC, `putStr` gets the lock on a Handle, so it should be atomic.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson no, there is no output to console, only writing files.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Do writes straight to a file not have this problem?

Comment: For starters, check your keyboard for cats.

Comment: Wait. `processI` writes to files, not the terminal, yet your _terminal_ is flooded with gibberish?

Comment: yes @DanielFischer, no output to stdout, only reading and writing files. And the terminal is flooded only with +RTS.

Comment: @Yrogirg, I'm guessing we'll need more code to determine what's going on here.. but I may be wrong.

Comment: Then it's probably `stderr`, not `stdout` that's flooded. Do different `processI`s try to write to the same file?

Comment: @DanielFischer Maybe he's getting error/warning messages that are garbled?

Comment: @Yrogirg Maybe try running with something less than -N8.. maybe you can make out what the text is (I'm suspecting errors/warnings).  If that's the case, synchronizing these writes should still solve this.

Comment: Oh, yes they were warnings. Data.Array.Repa had conflicts with Parallel.IO. It hasn't affected the actual output (the files written), only produced lots of distorted warnings.

Comment: @ehird Depends on the buffering, which means it depends on the terminal, I suppose.  `stdout` should only get interwoven lines by default (which is pretty bad already), but `stderr` can end up being interwoven character by character with other `stderr` output and with `stdout` output too.  Explicitly turning off buffering and `stdout` can be interwoven at the character level.

Comment: Perhaps you are making calls into foreign code (ex: a C library) that isn't thread safe?

Answer (score 6):

Buffering is probably preventing you from constructing a simple test case.  I was able to reproduce it with this (only when run with +RTS -Nsomething):

```
import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    forkIO $ putStrLn "foo"
    forkIO $ putStrLn "bar"
    forkIO $ putStrLn "baz"
    threadDelay 1000    -- Allow things to print
```

As Thomas mentioned, you'll probably need to sequence this somehow, though I'm not sure how writing straight to files would change this.  Here's a simple example how you can sequence this with a `Chan`.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this, this is just an example of how I got this to not garble the output.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Chan
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering

    ch <- newChan            -- Things written here are picked up by stuffWriter
    forkIO $ stuffWriter ch  -- Fire up concurrent stuffWriter

    forkIO $ writeChan ch "foo"
    forkIO $ writeChan ch "bar"
    forkIO $ writeChan ch "baz"
    threadDelay 1000         -- Allow things to print

-- | Write all the things!
stuffWriter :: Chan String -> IO ()
stuffWriter ch = do
    readChan ch >>= putStrLn -- Block, then write once I've got something
    stuffWriter ch           -- loop... looking for more things to write
```

Now your writes to somewhere are now synchronous (`stuffWriter` writes things, one at a time), and you should have no more garbling.

Comment: Did you understand that there is no output to terminal (i.e. no putStrLn) in my program?

Comment: yes, writes to files and terminal should be very similar, as putStr/putStrLn is just a special case of hPutStr (with the implicit stdout file handle)

Comment: either way, the concept is still the same... if you write things to a `Chan`, and your function that reads from it is run synchronously,  anything that's giving you troubles due to concurrency or parallelism, should be solved, because things are now done one at a time.

Comment: Could you please explain (or provide links) what is being outputed to terminal with +RTS? Where does all this random text come from?

Comment: I see... are you writing anywhere?  If so, is the file you are writing to still generated correctly even with run with +RTS?  You just have extra junk show up in the terminal?